# Exponential diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

Need some help regarding the equation $$2^a-3^b=(2^c-1)\cdot d >0$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers; $a,b$  are fixed; and $c>2$.

Can we show that $c,d$ exist? Thank you!

Comment: So, what you're asking is whether every integer of the form $2^a-3^b$ has a divisor of the form $2^c-1$?

Answer (score 0):

No. A counterexample is $2^6-3^3=37$, which is prime and not of the form $2^c-1$.

Comment: Thank you wythagoras. What can we say rearranging the equation with 2^c+1, with sufficiently large a,b?

Comment: I think for neither 2^c-1 nor 2^c+1 it is going to hold for all sufficiently large a,b, but that is pure conjecture.

Comment: There exist sufficiently large a,b such that it holds. For example 8-3=5 is a divisior of 8^n-3^n=2^3n-3^n for all n.

Comment: How we should proceed in order to see if, with sufficiently large and fixed a,b, there always exist c? Any idea...?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest, that is exactly why I conjecture that is not true.